# Does the chain of inequalities $\liminf_{n\to +\infty} f(x_n)\le f(x_n)\le\limsup_{n\to +\infty} f(x_n)$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f$ be a real valued function. Let $(x_n)_n$ be a real sequence.

Is true that
$$\liminf_{n\to +\infty} f(x_n)\le f(x_n)\le\limsup_{n\to +\infty} f(x_n)?$$

I know that for every sequence
$$\liminf_{n\to +\infty} x_n\le\limsup_{n\to +\infty} x_n,$$
but I don't know how to prove that the former chain of inequalities is true.

Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint:  Look at $(c,0,0,...)$

Comment: You should look at definitions of limsup and limsup. Let $\epsilon>0$ and then from a certain value of $n$ onwards we have $\liminf x_n-\epsilon\leq x_n\leq \limsup x_n+\epsilon$. But we don't have the above inequality for $\epsilon=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the “chain of inequalities’’ is false. It can even be false for infinitely many $n$; consider the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n/n$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the sequence $(x_n)$, where $x_n=(-1)^n2^{-n}$, and let $f$ be the function $f(x)=x$. Check to see that the proposed string of inequalities does not hold for *any* nonnegative integer $n$.

This extends to contiuous functions. Graph, say $e^{-x}\sin(x)$, or even $x^2e^{-x}\sin(x)$.